# Distinta ImageButton en el mismo MainActivity

Tags: java, android

No consigo ponerle dos acciones distintas a dos `ImageButton` distintos en el mismo `MainActivity`, poniendo la función solamente al primer `ImageButton`, si funciona, pero al poner la función al segundo, me sale:

> error: reached end of file while parsing

```
package prueba.otrointento;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static prueba.otrointento.R.id.btn1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton1

                );
            }

            ImageButton btn2;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

                btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(boton2

                        );
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo esta incorrecto. Dentro del `onCreate` de tu activity, creas un `Listener` para tu btn1. Luego de configurar lo que hace el click en tu boton, VUELVES A CREAR EL METODO `onCreate` dentro del evento `click` de tu boton y eso es incorrecto. Te dejo el codigo como deberia estar :

```
package prueba.otrointento;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static prueba.otrointento.R.id.btn1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton1);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Me vuelve a marcar el mismo error: "error: reached end of file while parsing" , gracias!

Comment: @UserNameYo actualice!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Estoy empezando y me has ayudado mucho, llevaba un rato ya intentando solucionarlo. Pero aprendo rápida ! Gracias de nuevo

Comment: exito @UserNameYo! recuerda marcar como correcta si soluciono tu problema, saludos!